# Is there an alternative to using an iPhone armband?

Tags: running

Running with a phone in my pocket is distracting due to the constant jiggle in my shorts. I have an iPhone 6. I need the phone tight to my body. Before I get an armband, I want to explore other options. I have an Apple Watch, and I believe an armband would defeat the purpose. I do not need the phone to be in a special position for fitness tracking, I just need to carry the phone. I really do not want to spend over $50 unless absolutely necessary. What is the best option?

Comment: I use a tiny sansa clip for mp3's and headphones made for running that wrap around the ear. I don't like have armbands or anything remotely heavy on my body.

Comment: Alternative..... sell the Watch, get say a Sony Smart Watch 3, or any watch with a built in GPS & wi-fi and you can leave the phone at home, and still track your runs ;)

Comment: Actually, i'm a  developer. I use Watch OS 2, which means I don't need the iPhone. The watch becomes standalone and has wifi access. I just need my phone, I can't leave it lying around. @arobber11

Comment: You realize you can get armbands for €5? Just bought one yesterday~ Just steer clear of Apple and their margins.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about armband recommendations.

Comment: Lol this is like a year old and its already answered. What's with the sudden attention @JohnP

Comment: It came up in the feed and had an answer flagged as spam. I hadn't seen it a year ago and wasn't a moderator then either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider getting a belt with a pocket. There are commercial running belts. Moneybelts will work a good bit of the time. I personally have one that my mom stitched together for me that works very well for my purposes. All of these solutions hold the phone up against your body, so there's very little jiggle or rubbing.

Personally, I sometimes just carry my tablet when if I don't have my little backpack for it. I'm sure carrying a phone won't be too much more of a burden.

Comment: Do you know a website that I can visit to see what it is?

Comment: A running belt? Type "Running belt" into Google and it will bring up several options. I didn't plan on adding any links simply because there are so many different manufacturers.

Comment: Okay, I was just looking for preferences, but I think I found something. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I bought the [Spydergrip](http://spydergrip.com/) because I couldn't find anything better out there. I am glad I did because I will never go back to an armband. I love my Spyder.

[image: Spydergrip image]

Comment: Huh. This one is a lot closer to what I initially asked my Mom to make for me. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I use the [HB Tune](http://www.hbtune.com) hand band. It wraps around your hand and holds your phone without requiring you to grip it.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use the bodyband it's a comforatable design and it allows for you to re-attach your cellphone with ease and no slipping. Here is the link [www.bodybandusa.com](http://www.bodybandusa.com), cheers!!